# Problem With Creating View, Invalid Column

Tags: sql, azure

I'm trying to create a view of the number of orders each customer places each year from the Northwind database. However, I'm getting the error message "Column 'Northwind.dbo.Orders.OrderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" on Azure Data Studio. My code is below.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vCustomerOrderCounts AS 
SELECT 
  CompanyName,
  Count(OrderID) AS 'NumberOfOrders',
  Year(OrderDate) AS 'Order Year'
FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers, Northwind.dbo.Orders
GROUP BY CompanyName;
GO

SELECT * FROM vCustomerOrderCounts
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using? `sql` just language

Comment: I'm using Azure Data Studio @dwir182

Comment: If you group by CompanyName then you can only have CompanyName or aggregate expressions in your result set. You cannot have YEAR(OrderDate) because it's not an aggregate expression

Comment: If I don't group by CompanyName, I get a different error. It says 'Northwind.dbo.Customers.CompanyName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You can't put `orderdate` in group by?

Comment: @dwir182 If OP does that then the count(OrderID) will be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` are not compatible.  In addition, I strongly encourage you to use column names that do not need to be escaped:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vCustomerOrderCounts AS 
    SELECT c.CompanyName,
           Count(*) AS NumberOfOrders,
           Year(o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear
    FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers c JOIN
         Northwind.dbo.Orders o
         ON c.customerId = o.customerId -- or whatever the JOIN conditions are
    GROUP BY c.CompanyName, Year(o.OrderDate);
```

Comment: This solved my issue with the view, but it looks like it is counting incorrectly. I'm getting really large number compared with the output I'm supposed to get. Any ideas on what I did wrong?